# Is it possible for an Android app to access a reminder set by a voice command or calendar

Tags: android-notifications

I am working on an app to enhance reminder functionality. I would like to be able to access the information about reminders set via the calendar app or by voice command.

I am able to use a ContentResolver to read a set of calendars, and a set of all events (per calendar, or globally), and a set of all "Reminders" (per calendar, or globally).

But, the reminders I get are only those that are associated with a calendar event. Apparently the reminders set by voice or from the Calendar application are different. I can't find them. I am testing using a Pixel 2 with Android version 9.